# How to iterate through a field list in a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, loops

I couldn't really figure out how to word the question so I will just explain what I am trying to do in a simpler or faster way.

I have a class called `GearBoxInfo` that is used for storing the various properties of a gearbox. Inside `GearBoxInfo` is a field called `GearSets` which is type `List<GearSet>`. The `GearSet` class has a field called `Gears` which is of type `List<Gear>`.

I am trying to loop through each `Gear` inside the `GearBoxInfo`, but to do that I need to also loop through each `GearSet` inside the `GearBoxInfo`, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gearBoxInfo.GearSets.Count; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < gearBoxInfo.GearSets[i].Gears.Count; i++) {
        Gear g = gearBoxInfo.GearSets[i].Gears[j];
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this (e.g. some LINQ function), as nested loops may take a long time. In the future, I may need to iterate through a field of `Gear`, for example, which would require another nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

[SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) is exactly what you are after, it flattens collections into one sequence:

```
var gears = gearBoxInfo.GearSets.SelectMany(gs=>gs.Gears);
```

More examples [here](http://dotnetpattern.com/linq-selectmany-operator)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you need to loop.  Do you need to iterate through each gear for a specific reason or are you looking for a specific gear? If you're looking for a specific gear you could use the .Find() or .First() methods.

```
for (var i = 0; i < gearBoxInfo.GearSets.Count; i++) {
    Gear g = gearBoxInfo.GearSets.First(f => f == "XYZ123");
    /* ... */
}
```